# Updates the `initialNavigation` property for `RouterModule.forRoot`. × Migration failed: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: typescript, angular

При переходе с 10-й версии ангуляра на 11-ю, возникает данная ошибка:

Updates the `initialNavigation` property for `RouterModule.forRoot`.
× Migration failed: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Файл с ошибками:

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.getImportOfIdentifier (D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\utils\typescript\imports.js:24:45)
at Object.isExtraOptions (D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\migrations\initial-navigation\util.js:37:31)
at InitialNavigationCollector.getLiteralNeedingMigration (D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\migrations\initial-navigation\collector.js:96:24)
at InitialNavigationCollector.visitNode (D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\migrations\initial-navigation\collector.js:48:44)
at D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\migrations\initial-navigation\collector.js:55:49
at visitNodes (D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30052:30)
at Object.forEachChild (D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30303:24)
at InitialNavigationCollector.visitNode (D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\migrations\initial-navigation\collector.js:55:20)
at D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\@angular\core\schematics\migrations\initial-navigation\collector.js:55:49
at visitNode (D:\Work\Bars-group\Projects\vmp-frontend\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30043:24)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась переходом с TypeScript 3.9.7 на 4.0.5